# Is the following conjecture relating to the chromatic number correct

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Define $\mu(G)$ as the minimum number  $k$ so that we can partition $V$ in $n, 1<n<k+1$  sets $V_i$ and so that every set $V_i$ has less than $k$ edges between $V_i$ and $V_i^c$

Let $G=(V,E)$ be k-chromatic and critical in the sense that deleting any vertex would reduce the chromatic number.

Is it correct that then $\mu(G) = k$

Comment: For a triangle, $\mu(G) = 3$, but $k = 2$

Comment: it does not, i'll edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: @caduk a triangle is 3 chromatic

Comment: Yes, $\mu (G) =3$. But i guess you meant a strict inequality with "less than". If you have a  bridge, then $k=2$, but it is not necessarily  $2$-colorable

Comment: Ah, forgot the criticality

Answer (score 1):

When trying to satisfy the definition of $\mu(G)$, we wouldn't actually want to partition $V$ into more than $2$ sets; that would just create more conditions for us to satisfy. So we might as well define $\mu(G)$ as the least $k$ so that we can partition $V = V_1 \cup V_2$ with fewer than $k$ edges between $V_1$ and $V_2$. In other words, $\mu(G) = \kappa'(G)+1$, where $\kappa'(G)$ is the edge connectivity of $G$.

The conjecture says that if $G$ is a $k$-vertex-critical graph, then $\kappa'(G) = k-1$.

We can prove a lower bound of this type: if $G$ is $k$-vertex-critical, then $\kappa'(G) \ge k-1$. To see this, suppose that $V(G)$ has a partition $V_1 \cup V_2$ with at most $k-2$ edges between $V_1$ and $V_2$. By assumption, $G[V_1]$ and $G[V_2]$ are both $(k-1)$-colorable. Take $(k-1)$-colorings of $G[V_1]$ and of $G[V_2]$, then randomly permute the colors of $G[V_2]$. For each edge between $V_1$ and $V_2$, there is a $\frac1{k-1}$ chance that this will result in both of its endpoints getting the same color, so the probability is at most $\frac{k-2}{k-1} < 1$ that this will happen for any of the $k-2$ edges. Therefore there is some permutation of the colors of $G[V_2]$ that results in no conflicts, and we get a $(k-1)$-coloring of $G$; contradiction.

However, it is not necessarily true that $\kappa'(G) \le k-1$. To see this, let $G$ be the graph join $C_5 + C_5$ (that is, two disjoint copies of $C_5$ with all $25$ edges between them). You can find this graph on House of Graphs [here](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/142). This graph is $6$-vertex-critical: if you remove a vertex from one $C_5$, then you can color the rest of that $C_5$ with only $2$ colors, and use $3$ more colors on the other $C_5$. However, $\kappa'(G)=7$ (I'm citing House of Graphs on this one, because the proof seems tedious).